# О компиляции и конкретизации шаблонов С++

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Во всяких учебниках и туториалах прописано, что при конкретизации (создания из трафарета функции или класса конкретной функции или класса с конкретными подставленными типами) шаблона, гарантируется что один и тот же шаблон для определенного типа конкретизируется только один раз, независимо от того, в каких модулях (файлы ли это имеются ввиду???) происходит эта конкретизация. 
Но как компилятор выстраивает этот процесс конкретизации, если компиляция файлов происходит по отдельности???

Например:

у нас существует файл с определением шаблона, например, функции (для простоты)
Пусть он называется **template_definition.h**

имеются так же файлы **template_user_first.cpp** и **template_user_second.cpp**. В оба этих файлв мы подключаем наш шаблон 
(**include template_definition.h**), а так же вызываем определенную шаблонную функцию с типом параметра, скажем **int** (в обеих файлах с одним и тем же типом параметра int, соответственно). Поскольку компилятор обрабатывает файлы по отдельности, то при препроцессинге **template_user_first.cpp**, он вставляет в него определение шаблона, конкретизирует его для типа параметра **int** и компилирует получившийся код инстанции шаблона, как часть объектного файла 
**template_user_first.obj**.
Однако же, когда компилятор приступает к компиляции файла **template_user_second.cpp**, то он, по идее, забывает о том, что уже конкретизировал шаблон функции типом **int** и откомпилировал обьектный код.

Из этого размышления следует что шаблон конкретизируется два раза, мало того, если бы происходило так (а так ли это???), то при линковке, линковщик бы встретил одну и ту же функцию, определенную дважды!

Возможно компилятор, при компиляции пачки файлов имеет некий кэш для конкретизаций шаблонов (первое что приходит в голову), но если так, то при раздельной компиляции и линковке существует возможность того, что в финальной слинкованной программе не окажется определения необходимой функции, ведь она была конкретизирована в файле, который не был включен в линковку впоследствии.

В общем, повторяю вопрос после всего описанного:
Как в реальности происходит данный процесс компиляции и конкретизации шаблонов?!

Comment: всё верно, если в файлах template_user_first.cpp и template_user_second.cpp конкретизировать одинаковый шаблон, то при линковке будет ошибка "ваш конкретизированный шаблон" already defined in template_user_first.obj

Comment: Есть такая штука, как автоматическое определение типа шаблонного параметра функции, без явного указания в треугольных скобках <> конкретного типа)
И в этом случае, если я вызову в обеих файлах функу с тем же самым типом, вылетит ошибка линковки???

Answer (score 1):

Все правильно, компилятор делает по определению функции в каждой из единиц трансляции, а линковщик произвольно выбирает из двух.

> гарантируется что один и тот же шаблон для определенного типа конкретизируется только один раз

В отличие от некоторых других языков, в С++ ничего такого не гарантируется. Ситуация, когда определения одной и той же шаблонной функции в разных единицах трансляции отличаются, является Неопределённым Поведением.